# How ROS vs. ROS 2 compare for Spot Boston Dynamics Robot

Tags: ros, ros2, package

I'm wondering what are some differences between the [ROS](https://github.com/heuristicus/spot_ros) and [ROS 2](https://github.com/bdaiinstitute/spot_ros2) packages for the Boston Dynamics Spot robot? What is their level of support? How is their functionality in relation to the official [Spot SDK](https://dev.bostondynamics.com/readme) and Python and C++ APIs? And what has your experience with the ROS/ROS2 packages been like?

As of time of writing, I've installed the ROS 2 package, but found the starter code in the README to not run successfully. Additionally, the repository has 10 Pull Requests and 10 Issues, some several weeks old.